# Join unrelated tables(A,B) with some condition on basis of table A for postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to join two unrelated tables, both table has a common column, a foreign key of third table, If suppose first table is Notification table, and second table is Photos table. A device takes photo on basis of several criteria on timely basis, if any movements, and also on basis of notifications. Need to pick both notifications and only one photo after that notification.

```
Notification Table
+-----+----------------------------+----------+----------------+
| id1 |  Notification timestamp    |   data1  |    deviceID    |
+-----+----------------------------+----------+----------------+
| 11  |  2020-10-26 22:31:33.602   | 2038.75  |        6       |
| 12  |  2020-10-26 22:31:34.001   | 2043.5   |        2       |
| 13  |  2020-10-26 22:51:47.178   | 1778.75  |        8       |
| 14  |  2020-10-26 23:12:07.761   | 2015.75  |        3       |
| 15  |  2020-10-26 23:12:09.611   | 2005.75  |        2       |
| 16  |  2020-10-26 23:12:09.122   | 1963.25  |        7       |
| 17  |  2020-10-26 23:12:11.930   | 694.75   |        2       |
+-----+----------------------------+----------+----------------+

Photo Table
+-----+---------------------------+----------+----------------+
| id2 |    Photo timestamp        |   data2  |    deviceID    |
+-----+---------------------------+----------+----------------+
| 21  |  2020-10-26 22:31:34.016  |     5    |        2       |
| 22  |  2020-10-26 22:31:34.102  |    75    |        6       |
| 23  |  2020-10-26 22:31:34.022  |    20    |        3       |
| 24  |  2020-10-26 22:51:47.97   |    55    |        2       |
| 25  |  2020-10-26 22:51:47.975  |    63    |        7       |
| 26  |  2020-10-26 22:51:47.977  |    19    |        4       |
| 27  |  2020-10-26 22:51:47.978  |    77    |        8       |
| 28  |  2020-10-26 23:12:07.613  |    44    |        6       |
| 29  |  2020-10-26 23:12:08.61   |    11    |        3       |
| 30  |  2020-10-26 23:12:09.625  |    51    |        2       |
| 31  |  2020-10-26 23:12:09.628  |    63    |        7       |
| 32  |  2020-10-26 23:12:10.635  |    19    |        4       |
| 33  |  2020-10-26 23:12:11.635  |    77    |        8       |
| 34  |  2020-10-26 23:12:12.235  |    44    |        6       |
| 35  |  2020-10-26 23:12:12.435  |    11    |        3       |
| 36  |  2020-10-26 23:12:12.650  |    51    |        2       |
+-----+---------------------------+----------+----------------+

Resultant Table
+---------------------------+----------+---------------------------+----------+----------------+
|  Notification timestamp   |   data1  |    Photo timestamp        |   data   |    deviceID    |
+---------------------------+----------+---------------------------+----------+----------------+
| 2020-10-26 22:31:33.602   | 2038.75  |  2020-10-26 22:31:34.102  |    75    |        6       |
| 2020-10-26 22:31:34.001   | 2043.5   |  2020-10-26 22:31:34.016  |     5    |        2       |
| 2020-10-26 22:51:47.178   | 1778.75  |  2020-10-26 22:51:47.978  |    77    |        8       |
| 2020-10-26 23:12:07.761   | 2015.75  |  2020-10-26 23:12:08.61   |    11    |        3       |
| 2020-10-26 23:12:09.611   | 2005.75  |  2020-10-26 23:12:09.625  |    51    |        2       |
| 2020-10-26 23:12:09.122   | 1963.25  |  2020-10-26 23:12:09.628  |    63    |        7       |
| 2020-10-26 23:12:11.930   | 694.75   |  2020-10-26 23:12:12.650  |    51    |        2       |
+---------------------------+----------+---------------------------+----------+----------------+
```

Tried with joining sub-queries. Definitely not a correct way to do though

```
select "notification".*, "filter_data".* FROM public.notification 
  left JOIN
    ( select "photo"."time", "photo"."data2", "photo"."deviceid", "notification"."id" as "eid", "notification"."time" as "etime" 
      from public."photo" inner join  public."notification" on "notification"."deviceid" = "photo"."deviceid" where 
      "photo"."time" >= "notification"."time" order by "photo"."time" ASC
      limit 1 
    )
  filter_data on "filter_data"."did" = "notification"."deviceid" 
  where "notification"."time" > date '2021-10-28 01:37:20.305+00' - interval '7 days'
  order by "notification"."device" ASC, "notification"."time" DESC limit 100;
```

Kindly suggest. I am aware my solution is not right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html) to get just a single Notification+Photo. The problem being that id1 in Notification is not unique (typo?). Note that sorting the [age](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) function gives the minimum time between the Notification and the Photo. (See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=76f55470fc2acde7e11cd0c9b1315d60))

```
select distinct on (n.id1,n.deviceid) 
       n.ts       "Notification Time" 
     , n.data1    "Notification Data"
     , p.ts       "Photo Time" 
     , p.data2    "Photo Data" 
     , n.deviceid "Device Id"      
  from notifications  n
  left join photos    p
         on (     p.deviceid = n.deviceid
              and p.ts > n.ts
            )      
 order by n.id1,n.deviceid,age(p.ts,n.ts);
```

Comment: yep typo ^_^ just corrected, Thank you! your query does the job pretty neat!

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
WITH list AS
(
SELECT n.Notification, n.data1, n.deviceID, first_value(p.Photo) OVER (ORDER BY p.Photo ASC) AS Photo
     , p.data2, p.deviceID
  FROM Notification AS n
 INNER JOIN Photo AS p
    ON p.deviceID = n.deviceID
   AND p.Photo >= n.Notification
 GROUP BY n.Notification, n.data1, n.deviceID
)
SELECT l.Notification, l.data1, l.Photo, p.data2 AS data, l.deviceID
  FROM list AS l
 INNER JOIN Photo AS p
    ON l.deviceID = p.deviceID
   AND l.Photo = p.Photo
```